# Angular Modal is not showing shadow properly

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I'm implementing Angular Modal, using [ngx-bootstrap/modal](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap)

When i've clicked in a link which open my modal, the modal it's opened, but without shadow.

Did anybody face this problem? I would like help to fix this problem. I didn't find any description about this issue on forums.

Follow snapshot below:

[image]

I've tried:

Package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.4",
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1", 
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
"rxjs": "~6.4.0",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"zone.js": "~0.9.1"
```

},

```
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
private service: Services,
private modalService: BsModalService) {
this.id = this.route.snapshot.params["id"];
```

}

open method:

```
open(erro) {
debugger;

const initialState = {
  erro: erro
};

//this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ErroModalComponent, { initialState });
this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(
  ErroModalComponent,
  Object.assign({ initialState }, { class: 'modal-lg' })
);
```

}

HTML of block which has being repeated

```
<tr *ngFor="let erro of errors" (click)="open(erro)" class="opcao">
    <th scope="row">{{erro.idEPS}}</th>
    <td>{{erro.machineName}}</td>
    <td>{{erro.logged}}</td>
    <td>{{erro.level}}</td>
    <td>{{erro.message}}</td>
  </tr>
```

HTML Modal Block

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use MatDialog to open modal dialogs using angular material design https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: can you add the code you tried

Comment: Did you add the Bootstrap CSS?

Comment: Yes, all components have been loaded sucessfully, except shadow of the modal. It's possible to see this in the above print screen. I've complemented the code with this information. Thanks.